# Unpacking a tuple to call a function templated with variadic arguments in a subclass implementations (C++)

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, variadic

I am in the midst of implementing an [Entity Component System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system). I am running into issues when attempting to call a function templated with variadic arguments:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct engine_system : engine_system_base<Ts>... {
    using component_types = std::tuple<Ts...>;

    // subclass implements this
    virtual void process_values(float delta_time, Ts&... ts) const = 0;
    
    void update(float delta_time) const {
        auto component_view = registry.get_view<Ts...>();
        for (component_types& c : component_view){
            process_values(delta_time, ?????);  // issue
        }
    }
};
```

The `engine_system_base` takes care of registering `T` for each type in `Ts`. On `update` each system implementation is supposed to retrieve all necessary components from the registry. I am unfortunately not sure how I can unpack the `component_types` instance to correctly call a subclass implementation.

Here is a full example (registry omitted):

```
// components are just "plain old data"
struct vec3 {
    float x, y, z;
};

struct transform_component {
    vec3 position, rotation, scale;
};

struct rigid_body_component {
    vec3 velocity, acceleration;
};
```

Components store state and have no behavior. Systems implement behavior based on Components.

```
// internal systems
template <typename T>
struct engine_system_base {
    engine_system_base() { /* register T for system in registry */ };
    virtual ~engine_system_base() = default;
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct engine_system : engine_system_base<Ts>...{
    using component_types = std::tuple<Ts...>;

    virtual void process_values(float delta_time, Ts&... ts) const = 0;
    
    void update(float delta_time) const {
        auto component_view = registry.get_view<Ts...>();
        for (auto& c : component_view){
            process_values(delta_time, ?????); // issue
        }
    }
};
```

`engine_system_base` registers `T` for a subclass implementation. `engine_system` uses `engine_system_base` as a variadic base to register each `T` in `Ts` with the registry (omitted). Afterward, a system can be implemented as such:

```
struct move_system : engine_system<transform_component, const rigid_body_component> {
    void process_values(float delta_time, transform_component& tc, const rigid_body_component& rb) const final {
        tc.position += rb.velocity * delta_time;
    }
};
```

The `move_system` can then be used to translate all entities, which are comprised of a `transform_component` and `rigid_body_component`.

```
int main() {
    move_system ms{};
    ms.update(0.016); 
    return 0;
}
```

In my first implementation, I defined `void update(float delta_time) const` individually for each system implementation, which works but duplicates the same exact implementation and only differs in by explicitly defining `Ts...` for each subclass. Unfortunately, I am running into the aforementioned issue when attempting to refactor this logic into `engine_system`.

Comment: Did you consider `std::apply` ?

Comment: just a side question: why don't you use EnTT? It has great API and great functionality

Comment: @paolo I did not; I am not sure how that would look like though? Got a suggestion?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik I am aware of EnTT and I regularly use it as a reference implementation and a source of inspiration. I am fairly new to C++ and simply want to implement an ECS to get myself more familiar with the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `component_view` type is `component_types`, [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) might help:

```
void update(float delta_time) const {
    auto component_view = registry.get_view<Ts...>();
    for (auto& c : component_view){
        std::apply([&](auto&... args){ process_values(delta_time, args...); }, c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `?????` with `std::get<Ts>(c)...` assuming that each `T` in `Ts` is unique.

In case you have non-unique `Ts`, as mentioned in comments, you can use a [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence):

```cpp
[&]<auto... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  process_values(delta_time, std::get<Is>(c)...);
}(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});
```

Comment: Right now I can guarantee that each `T` in `Ts` is unique. Thanks a lot, it works. Out of curiously though, is there a solution where `T` may not be unique?

Comment: @matreska - The other option is to use `get<index>(Ts)...` using a generated [std::index_sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence). Probably with another layer of indirection.